Slack API x Google Apps Script - Trying to set a new photo with users.setPhoto
I'm developing an App with Google Apps Script and need to change the profile user's photo from a specific user.
The flow is as follows:
The HR person will choose a photo from your computer and click the save button to save the photo in the Slack profile photo.
I'm trying to use the users.setPhoto to change the user's photo but it throws a lot of different errors, like bad_image, and invalid_arg_name.
On front-end I'm sending the image:
$('#upload_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var fileInput = document.getElementsByClassName('input_file');
    var originalFile = fileInput[0].files[0]
    var newFileName = email.split('@')[0] + '.' + originalFile.name.split('.').pop()
    var newFile = new File([originalFile], newFileName, { type: originalFile.type })

    console.log('newFile', newFile)
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        var content = e.target.result
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
                    
            console.log(result)

        }).withFailureHandler(function(e) {

            console.log(e)

        }).test(content)
    }
    var newFileRead = reader.readAsDataURL(newFile)
            
})

On the back end, I'm receiving the image and sending a post request to https://slack.com/api/users.setPhoto
function test(content) {
    var id = idUserTest()
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(content, "image/jpeg", "testImagejpeg.jpeg");
    updateUserProfilePhoto(id, blob)
}

function updateUserProfilePhoto(userId, image) {
    var accessToken = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('ACCESS_TOKEN')
    var url = 'https://slack.com/api/users.setPhoto'

    Logger.log('image: ' + JSON.stringify(image))
    
    var payload = {
        image: image,
        user_id: userId
    }

    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            
        },
        payload: payload,
        muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    try {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        Logger.log(jsonResponse);
        if (jsonResponse.ok) {
            Logger.log('Photo update successful');
        } else {
            Logger.log(`Error on update profile's photo: ${jsonResponse.error}` );
        }
    } catch (error) {
        Logger.log('Error on request: ' + error.toString());
    }
}

I already tried to change the "Content-Type" and a lot of the things in the script but, not worked yet.
